# Ruby RegEx to Match between . and :

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string: "51. some thing:" 
 and would like to extract just "some thing" using reg ex in ruby. Can anyone point me in the right direction to match between a . and a : and discard everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'51. some thing:'.sub /.*\. *([^:]*).*/, '\1'
=> "some thing"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
(?<=\.).+?(?=:)
```

If you want to avoid leading and trailing spaces in the match, you can use this:

```
(?<=\.\s*)\S.*?(?=\s*:)
```

**Edit:** I just checked and noticed that Ruby doesn't support lookbehind, which is used here. Alternatively, you can use this and take the capture of the regex as result:

```
\.\s*(\S.*?)\s*:
```

Comment: The first solution listed here works now as Ruby currently supports lookbehind.